# Passing jQuery variable to PHP on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I know this is a frequent question on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find scenario where the PHP code is just above JS script in the same file. I guess ajax POST/GET won't do the job in this case?

```
(...)
var ww = $(window).width();
   </script>

<?php $ww = [data here] ?>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your code?

Comment: I blame Frontpage. Not everyone can build a website, nor should everyone.

Comment: @Rob W I need to display 100%-wide image using Timthumb, width: 100% won't do the job because image have to be cropped.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. You'd like a width of `100%`, and also a "Cropped image"? It's possible to crop the image using HTML/CSS only: **1)** `<img src=".." width=100 height-100>` **2)** `<span style="width:150px;height:150px"><img src=".." style="width:100%;height:100%" /></span>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **will** have to use POST/GET to send a JS variable to PHP, because PHP is processed by the server and JS is processed by the client.

I know this isn't what you want to hear.

Answer (score 3):

This is the wrong approach.  The PHP is all parsed / evaluated server side.  Later, the users' browser gets to parse / evaluate the javascript.  Even if the JS appears before the PHP in your file, the PHP is still evaluated server side before anything is passed to the browser.  If you need client side values passed back to the server, you use AJAX for that.  You can make decisions on the server side again, and in the response, trigger the JavaScript to take some action based on the decision the PHP made, but you don't get to mix / match client / server actions in a single file like this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way, because javascript runs on your local machine **AFTER** PHP has been executed and has returned HTML/CSS/JS to your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would use AJAX to pass what I need to the server to be processed, then based on the response, using Javascript, make any necessary adjustments. For example:

```
***PHP File***
<?php
$ww = $_POST['data'];
$result = doSomethingWithVariable($ww);
echo $result;
```

---

```
***HTML File***
<script>
...
var ww = $(window).width();
$.ajax({
    url: 'phpfile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data : ww },
    success: function (result) {
        doSomethingWithResult(result);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did recently was passing a variable value to the attribute of an element that was dynamically generated by php. Then using the get attr() function of jquery to get the value. Worked perfectly!

PHP part:

```
foreach ((array)$photos['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
$Maxcount++;
}

foreach ((array)$photos['photos']['photo'] as $photo) { 
echo "<img imgID='$IDcount' Maxcount='$Maxcount'
```

jQuery:

```
 var maxCount= $(".imageView").attr("maxCount");
```