# Get last number of added fields with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I made a form where you can add more fields by clicking on a button. Everytime you click on a button it makes a new field with a higher number behind it. I do this with jquery and I need to get the highest number with php. 
So if I have auto_part1 and auto_part2 I need to get 2 with PHP.

This is my html:

```
<div id="parts">
    Part
    <input type="text" id="auto_part" name="auto_part" />
                <br />
    Description
    <input type="text" id="auto_description" name="auto_description" />
                <br />
</div>
    <a href="#" id="addField">Add another part</a>
```

The jQuery function:

```
$(function() {
var scntDiv = $('#parts');
var i = $('#parts input').size() + -1;

$('#addField').on('click', function() {
    $('<br /><span>Part</span> <input type="text" id="auto_part'+i+'" name="auto_part'+i+'" /><br />').appendTo(scntDiv);
    $('<span>Description</span> <input type="text" id="auto_description'+i+'" name="auto_description'+i+'" /> <br />').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
});

$('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
    if( i > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need?

Comment: you can't pass the field id to PHP unless you used AJAX

Comment: @Sedz: why not? He can set the value to a hidden field then submit the form to PHP.

Comment: @JeromyFrench my comment was about sending the id but sure you can send it with hidden field as a value not as an id, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @Sedz: no worries! Just didn't want to confuse poor Sinan...

Comment: @JeromyFrench, Yes I noticed that , thanks man for pointing it out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="row_count" name="row_count" value="">
```

And `onsubmit` do:

```
$('#row_count').val(i);
```

Comment: I think I would still have to use Ajax for this if I want to pass it to PHP right?

Comment: If you want to send in the value **before** you pass the form itself then yes. Otherwise the value is simply transmitted together with the rest of the form.

Comment: Indeed thats what I thought too I wont use the last line but I like the hidden field idea thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong Please use the stack overflow search too ..

here you can find a way ..

[Passing jQuery variable to PHP on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680571/passing-jquery-variable-to-php-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

Presumaby this is in a form that eventually gets submitted ?  If so how about having a hidden field that  gets incremented each time a new part field is added.  Then when it gets sent PHP can just grab that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field (`<input type="hidden" name="added_counter" id="added_counter" value="0" />`), maintain its value with your increment/decrement functions (`$('added_counter').val(i);`), then use PHP to get the value of the hidden field during processing of the form submission.

HTML:

```
<div id="parts">
    Part
    <input type="text" id="auto_part" name="auto_part" />
    <br />
    Description
    <input type="text" id="auto_description" name="auto_description" />
    <br />
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="added_counter" id="added_counter" value="0" />
<a href="#" id="addField">Add another part</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#parts');
    var i = $('#parts input').size() + -1;

    $('#addField').on('click', function() {
        $('<br /><span>Part</span> <input type="text" id="auto_part'+i+'" name="auto_part'+i+'" /><br />').appendTo(scntDiv);
        $('<span>Description</span> <input type="text" id="auto_description'+i+'" name="auto_description'+i+'" /> <br />').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        $('added_counter').val(i);
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                i--;
        }
        $('added_counter').val(i);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then when you submit the form to PHP, PHP can get the value of the new added_counter hidden field.

Comment: I'd prefer to set the value of the hidden field only upon submission of the form, instead of maintaining with each increment/decrement--but I gave you an example that works within your original code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of posted values to get the highest number. I posted the data as an array but you don't have to do it that way.

```
$('<br /><span>Part</span> <input type="text" id="auto_part'+i+'" name="parts['+i+'][name]" /><br />').appendTo(scntDiv);
$('<span>Description</span> <input type="text" id="auto_description'+i+'" name="parts['+i+'][description]" /> <br />').appendTo(scntDiv);


$parts=isset($_POST['parts'])?$_POST['parts']:array();
$highest_number=count($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed the way you are naming your added input fields. Instead of using:
     auto_part + i
use
    auto_part[]

Same with auto_description, name it auto_description[]. That way they will be seen by php as arrays and all you need to do is iterate over the arrays. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your html form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="count" value="0"/>
```

Add in your javascript, on the onclick event:

```
$('#count').val(i);
```

Then you can get the value you are looking for in the php as the value of the field count.